# Matlab: find minimum pixel in 2D with specific rgb

Tags: matlab

Lets suppose I have this image:

[image]

I need to get the minimum pixel with rgb = (0, 80, 41). to find the pixel I would do:

```
bart = imread('bart.jpg');

% Find pixels that have red=0, g = 80 or b = 41
r_find = find(bart(:, :, 1) == 0);
g_find = find(bart(:, :, 2) == 80);
b_find = find(bart(:, :, 3) == 41);

% intersect pixels to find pixels that his color are (0,80,41)
find_res = intersect(intersect(r_find, g_find), b_find);

%find the minimum pixel (1D)
pixel = min(find_res);
```

Yes, I have founded it, but how can I obtain x,y coordinates of pixel (2D)?

Comment: I think you have to specify what do you mean whith "minimum pixel". What is a minimum 2D coordinates for you?

Comment: hte fminimum (x,y) coordenates. It would be the top-left first green pixel

Comment: As @marcoresk said, you can't mininize _x_ and _y_ simultaneously. Do you want to minimize the sum of `x` and `y`? The largest of `x`and `y`? ...?

Comment: I don't know, I have to find the first left-top pixel that have RGB color (0,80,41) in 2D, but I don't kno how to do

Comment: @albert you may consider to minimize euclidean distance from the origin (top left corner) but also remember that find_res should be somehow a 2D array. Later I will post a solution in code

Comment: `find_res` gives you the indices of the green pixels, so `min(find_res)` would give you the index of the first of these (same as `find_res(1)`), so all you need to do now is `ind2sub`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is using `find` operation for each color channel separately.

The solution is simple applying the condition first:

```
[row, col] = find(((bart(:, :, 1) == 0) & (bart(:, :, 2) == 80) & (bart(:, :, 3) == 41)), 1)
```

The above example, minimize row coordinate first.

In case you need to minimize the column fist, you can transpose before applying `find`:

```
[col, row] = find([((bart(:, :, 1) == 0) & (bart(:, :, 2) == 80) & (bart(:, :, 3) == 41))]', 1)
```

---

Explain by example:

```
%Read input image
RGB = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sRiY.jpg');

%Unpack RGB planes (just for example purpose - you don't need to do it).
R = RGB(:, :, 1);
G = RGB(:, :, 2);
B = RGB(:, :, 3);

%(R == 0) is a logical matrix with 1 where condition is true, and 0 where false.
%Same think for (G == 80) and for (B == 41)
figure;imshow(R == 0);  %Same as imshow(RGB(:,:,1) == 0)
figure;imshow(G == 80);
figure;imshow(B == 41);
```

Images:
R == 0

[image]

G == 80
[image]

B == 41
[image]

```
%Now use AND operation between the three logical matrices:
A = ((RGB(:, :, 1) == 0) & (RGB(:, :, 2) == 80) & (RGB(:, :, 3) == 41));

%A is a logical matrix with 1 where condition is true, and 0 where false.
figure;imshow(A);
```

Image A:
[image]

```
%The following operation minimize column first:
%Find first index where A equals true (where value equals 1).
[col, row] = find(A, 1);

%In case you need to minimize the row first, you can transpose A:
[row, col] = find(A', 1);

%All operations in single statement:
[row, col] = find(((RGB(:, :, 1) == 0) & (RGB(:, :, 2) == 80) & (RGB(:, :, 3) == 41)), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can draw diagonal of the image (using `poly2mask` function) and find the first pixel along the diagonal that has specified value.

```
[rs ,cs,~] = size(bart); 
%create a mask image that has diagonal pixels value of 1
mask = poly2mask([0 cs cs], [0 rs rs],rs, cs);
%setting last argument to 1 to find the first pixel that meets the condition
[r c] = find(mask & bart(:, :, 1) == 0 & bart(:, :, 2) == 80 & bart(:, :, 3) == 41,1)
```

The more efficient is to find equation of the diagonal line using two corner points and only work with pixels along the line.